# I can link a .jar on compile time but not on run time

Tags: java, command-line

I compile java from the command line.

I can run:

```
javac test.java -cp jarfile.jar
```

Now i thought i could run (from the same folder)

```
java test -cp jarfile.jar
```

I also tried

java test

and

java test -cp jarfile

I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Is there any conceptual mistake?
Can I assume the Code is correct as I can compile it?

Comment: What is the complete stack trace of the exception? This could happen if `test` only depends on classes that are in the jarfile, but jarfile itself depends on classes that are in other libraries. Also, please respect Java naming conventions (`Test`, not `test`), and always put your classes in packages.

Comment: set your classpath first..

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Jama/Matrix
        at jtf.main(jtf.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Jama.Matrix
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: 2nd part:        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more

Comment: put a semicolon at last

Comment: There is an "edit" link at the bottom of your question. Click it, and paste the complete stacktrace, in a code block, in your question. Also, why do you tell us that your class is named `test` if it's actually named `jtf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that you're specifying the class name before the classpath - so it thinks that `-cp` is one of the command line arguments to your class, rather than an argument to the JVM to say where to find classes.

The second problem - potentially - is that you're not including the current directory in the classpath. You want:

```
java -cp jarfile.jar;. test
```

(on Windows) or

```
java -cp jarfile.jar:. test
```

(on Unix)

If you don't need any classes other than the ones in the jar file, of course, you just need:

```
java -cp jarfile.jar test
```

Or if you've included an appropriate manifest in your jar file, you can just use:

```
java -jar jarfile.jar
```